# Windows 10 5.1 speakers

Tags: google-chrome, audio, windows-10, speakers

I have a Realtek sound card and 5.1 speakers.

I had windows 7 until about month ago and everything worked perfectly. I had a Realtek "control panel", it contained functionality for the sound card, like adjusting speakers volume and choosing the speaker type.

Now I moved to windows 10 and this Realtek control panel is gone.

In addition, VLC and Chrome used to play sound using all the speakers and now in Windows 10 they play using only the 2 front speakers.

I read that the flash version might cause this problem but I installed the newest version (18.0).

I tried to remove the driver and install it again using the newest version from the Realtek website and it changed nothing.

In the audio panel in Windows I selected the 5.1 option and when I press test I can hear sound from all of the speakers. Yet, Chrome and VLC  doesn't play through them.

What can I do to make it work on windows 10?

Edit: In addition, each time i want to configure my speakers a message box pop up and say that the driver is causing problems and ask me if i want to disable it

Comment: Are you sure whatever you’re watching in Chrome/VLC is actually 5.1?

Comment: The media you are watching in VLC must support 5.1 audio.

Comment: I hear music from pandora and youtube on chrome, i dont know if it support 5.1 but it used to work on all speakers. I dont remember if i duplicated the audio to the rear speakers. If i did so, how can i do it again? i probably did it about 4 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-download the latest [Realtek drivers](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsCheck.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=14&PFid=24&Level=4&Conn=3&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false) from Realtek themselves, not the ones from Windows.

That should give you the control panel back again.

Comment: im stuck in endless loop of: "object moved to here". Anyway, i already downloaded the driver from this website and it didnt work.

Comment: then uninstall it/remove the device in device manager & reinstall again. If you don't have the correct control panel, you don't have the realtek version

Comment: where am i supposed to see it? in the small incons near the clock (forgot its name)

Comment: i downloaded again the newsest version. still no control panel